# dotnet 3.1 The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: deployment, compiler-errors, dependencies, version, .net-core-3.1

I have been struggling with this for two days now. I have looked all over the internet and tried many different things, all with no help.

I have a .NET Core 3.1 self contained solution with about 4 projects. I am building the application on my Windows desktop. When I push it to BitBucket, my pipeline runs. It looks like this:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script:
          # Restore, Publish and Release the .NET core project
          - dotnet restore
          - dotnet publish ProjectsApi.sln -c Release -r centos.7-x64 -o "deployment" --self-contained
        artifacts:
          - deployment/**
    - step:
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/sftp-deploy:0.5.3
            variables:
              REMOTE_PATH: $FTP_REMOTE_PATH
              USER: $FTP_USERNAME
              SERVER: $FTP_HOST
              LOCAL_PATH: $FTP_LOCAL_PATH
              EXTRA_ARGS: $FTP_PORT
```

The build succeeds and everything is uploaded to my Cent OS 7 server just fine. But when I try to run the application, I get the following:

> # ./ProjectApi.Api
>
> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
>   File name: 'System.ComponentModel, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

One thing to note is I was using System.ComponentModel at one point. I was using it for data annotations and was getting the same error. I removed them and removed the package just to see if it would fix the issue but it did not. When the package was added, it utilized version 4.3.0. I even tried to install version 4.0.4.0 just to see if that would help and got the same error.

I tried forcing it to recognize the new assembly but that did not work:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.0" newVersion="4.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I tried removing the dll from the deployment folder and replacing it with one I published from my machine and that did not help at all. I am all out of ideas. I can publish the solution and it runs just fine locally. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: @matt I resolved this by running the application on a clean centos 7 server. I had to reinstall everything but it worked fine. I think there was some issue with an old version of core still hanging around.Also, I did make one other change I think. For some reason when I created some of my projects it used an incorrect target framework in the .csproj file. Check to make sure the `<TargetFramework>` tag in the .csproj files is `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>` and not `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`